How do I fix this bathtub faucet handle?
This bathtub faucet handle fell off a couple days ago, I'm not sure how to put it back on (see pictures). There is no obvious screw that just needs to be tightened with an Allen wrench. I can push it down, but it only kinda connects, I think the inside of the handle is supposed to grip the base, but it doesn't connect solidly. Meanwhile it wobbles a lot and will easily fall off.
inside view
no allen screw
no allen screw
under the cap

The little dome cap on top should pop off to see where a screw goes.  Might need a thin bladed tool to pop off.

If a screw was in there holding it down, lets just say I am glad it is not mine.

You could probably pop the cap with a disposable chopstick from the interior side. And @crip659 — you’ve basically got an answer there.

My guess is that hole is too small for a disposable chopstick.  Something like a nail might work, though.

@crip659 the little dome did pop off (see additional photo above). It looks like I tighten with an Allen wrench? I'll try that and let ya'll know.

Hmm, I took the cap off the other faucet, and it looks like there is a tiny screw in there, that is not present on the broken side. Is this what you were talking about above, @crip659? Is there anything I can do about it? I don't see the tiny screw anywhere.

Yes.  It is possible the screw broke/rusted in two pieces, and one piece is still in the base that needs removing.  Replacing the whole faucet might be easier.  There are screw removing tools if that faucet is important/has sentimental value.  Also possible someone before lost the tiny screw and never put it in.  It basically just keeps you from pulling it up and off.  Do not pull on it.

@crip659 it sounds like it's not worth trying to fix it (no sentimental value) and we should just replace it.

The only thing that screw does is to keep people from just lifting the handle off.  Can just put the handle back on as is and have many more years of the faucet working.  Or use it as an excuse to get a new faucet.

Yeah, it works just fine, but the handle keeps coming of in my hand. Probably time to replace.
